# Why does executing iterator->end() in the immediate window give read access violation, even when the iterator is in scope - for C++ vector::iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, random-access

I have the following program:

```
int main()
{
    vector<vector<int> > vv;
    vector<int> v1;
    vector<int> v2;
    v1.push_back(1);
    v1.push_back(2);
    v1.push_back(3);

    v2.push_back(10);
    v2.push_back(20);
    v2.push_back(30);
    vv.push_back(v1);
    vv.push_back(v2);

    for (vector<vector<int> >::iterator it = vv.begin(); it != vv.end(); it++)
    {
        for (vector<int>::iterator col = it->begin(); col != it->end(); col++)
        {
            cout << *col << " ";
        } //<------- when the instruction pointer is here, and I type it->end() in the immediate window, I get correct result in the immediate window, but then after doing an F10 or F11, I get a read access violation.
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Why am I getting a read access violation, when I am only doing an `it->end()` in the immediate window (I am simply reading the value of `it->end()` and this should not give me a read access violation in this particular scenario)? Please note that the iterator `it` is in scope here and doing `it->end()` in the immediate window gives the following correct result:

```
it->end()
{-33686019}
    [ptr]: 0x010ce02c {-33686019}
    [Raw View]: {...}
```

Everything is alright until this point. But, next, when I do a F11 or F10 to go to the next instruction, I get a read access violation in the file - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\include\ **xmemory**.

Following is the exception in the file **xmemory**:
[image: Read access violation in file xmemory]

As the exception in the image above says (the exception is thrown at line 1286 in the file **xmemory**):

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
_Pnext was 0xCCC35DE9.
```

Clearly, 0xCC means `_Pnext` was uninitialized. And, hence, doing `*_Pnext` at line 1286 leads to Read Access Violation.

My question is that, I had simply done an `it->end()` in the immediate window, before just coming out of the while loop - as indicated in my main() program above. And, the iterator `it` was in scope at that time. And doing `it->end()` in the immediate window also gave me the correct result:

```
it->end()
{-33686019}
    [ptr]: 0x010ce02c {-33686019}
    [Raw View]: {...}
```

then, why did doing a F10 after that, resulted in a Read Access Violation at line 1286, in the file **xmemory**?

**Please see**: In the main() program, I have marked the closing brace  - **}** - where the exception is encountered. The instruction pointer reaches this closing brace, when the inner loop executes fully. On pressing F10 or F11 after that, the instruction pointer goes to the next statement - `cout << endl;` - if nothing is typed in the immediate window. Also, if I just run the main() program without debugging (that is, without debugging the way I showed here), the program executes fine, with the correct output. Please also note that when the inner loop does not execute fully (that is, when the closing brace - **}** - of the inner loop is not encountered) and, I execute `it->end()` in the immediate window - I get the correct result in the immediate window. And, I can proceed forward till the very end, by pressing F10 or F11. And the main() program outputs the correct result.

**Compiler and OS details**: Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (Version 16.2.1). I am building x86 Debug. 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor. Windows edition = Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue with Visual Studio 2017, using the same instructions that the OP provided for Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: I can also reproduce it in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: it->begin() or end()  ?-what's it supposed to be,  mustn't it be trash ? as end() is member fnc. of array/vector

Comment: I'm getting `it->end()
Function std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::end has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations.` in VS2019 16.4.2 MSVC 14.24.28314

Comment: I had tried with it->end(). it->end() return a pointer, whose contents are trash (as shown in the OP) : [ptr]: 0x010ce02c {-33686019}. I also tried with it->begin() instead of it->end(). it->begin() gave me the following result: [ptr]: 0x0082dfe8 {1}. I pressed F10 after that and, it resulted in the same read access violation at line 1286 in file xmemory (same line in the same file). The exception was the same - "_Pnext was 0xCC35DE9". 0xCC means _Pnext is uninitialized. And then we are dereferencing _Pnext. So, it is hitting the exact same exception. Could it be a bug, that I am hitting this?

Comment: @nonock - the exception also occurs when I execute it->begin() in the immediate window (as I stated in the above comment). Could it be a bug in Visual Studio?

Comment: Since nobody on StackOverflow seems to be able to help you (myself included), you may want to report this problem on the [Microsoft Visual Studio forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html). There, I believe Microsoft employees also sometimes provide a response. If you do so, it would be nice if you could provide a link to your report on that forum, because I would be interested in it myself.

Comment: Will ask the question to Microsoft, as soon as possible.